# Formula for a button in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have added a button in my email.

On click of the button the following formula runs:

```
@If(disablebutton="1"; 
    @Return(@Prompt([Ok];"";"Thank you but you have already clicked once! :) "));
    @Prompt([Ok];"";"Thank you for the click! :) "));
@MailSend( "abc@xyz.com"; ""; "" ; "I will be present at the event!" ; 
            "" ; "" ; [PriorityNormal] );
FIELD disablebutton:="1";
```

Above formula basically does the following:

```
if(disableButton is 1){
       Open prompt : you have already clicked and return without executing anything ahead
}else{
       Open prompt : Thank you for the click!
}

send email to the specified email address with specified subject

set disableButton = 1
```

So when the email is opened by the receiver, above formula restricts receiver to click button just once and as a result only one mail gets sent out to specified email address.

However, the issue is, if the user closes the mail and opens again, the same formula runs from the beginning which effectively allows receiver to send the mail again.

So effectively he can send as many mails to the specified email address by closing and opening the mail and clicking the button afresh.

How to deal with this ? I want the value of disableButton to persist permanently so that the mail gets sent out only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following lines at the end of your formula:

```
@If(@IsDocBeingEdited;
    @PostedCommand([FileSave]);
    @Do(    @PostedCommand([EditDocument]);
            @PostedCommand([FileSave]);
            @PostedCommand([EditDocument])))
```

Field setting keeps staying in document only if document is in edit mode and it gets saved. Usually, emails are in read mode when users read their emails. With `@Command([EditDocument]);` you can toggle between read and edit mode.

If the email is in *edit* mode we just need to save the document.

If the email is in *read* mode we change document to edit mode, save the document and set it back to read mode.

Comment: This solution throws a extra dialog box asking "if you want to save the changes or not"... is there a way to block the dialog box ? Otherwise what you suggested worked fine... thanks..

Comment: With `@PostedCommand(...)` it won't get asked you anymore because those lines will be executed after all other lines for sure this way. I changed my answer from `@Command(...)` to `@PostedCommand(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the update.. But I still get the "Do you want to save the changes?" dialog box..

Comment: I improved my answer: now it toggles between edit/read mode only if document is in read mode. This way you don't get the question "Do you want to save the changes?" anymore pressing your button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the same functionality in LotusScript. It's much easier - to debug - there.

```
dim uiws as new notesuiworkspace
dim uidoc as notesuidocument
dim disablebutton as string
dim doc as notesdocuemnt
set uidoc = uiws.currentDocument
disablebutton = uidoc.fieldgettext("DisableButton")
if(strcompare(disablebutton,"1",5)=0 then
messagebox {Thank you but you have already clicked once! :)}
else
call sendMail(uidoc.document)
set doc =uidoc.document
call doc.replaceitemvalue("DisableButton","1")
call doc.save(true,false)
call uidoc.close()
end if
```

The function SendMail needs to be implemented too.